# How to have Windows 7 store its desktop wallpaper file TranscodedWallpaper.jpg on a RAM disk (RAM drive)?

Tags: windows, windows-7, desktop-customization, ramdisk, transcode

Windows 7 (and later versions, to my knowledge) stores the current desktop's wallpaper as a transcoded image file named `TranscodedWallpaper.jpg`.

In Windows 7, the location of this file is`X:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg`.

This file gets automatically created by Windows every time the desktop background changes, including in slideshow mode.

I tried created compressed and non-compressed PNG and JPEG files as well as BMP files (all of the proper size, scale, and DPI) for the source background files, but Windows always created this transcoded image file.

Ideally, I would like to have Windows use the direct source file for the wallpaper (without creating an intermediate file), but after much searching, I did not find any reference to this being possible.

Assuming it is not possible to avoid using `TranscodedWallpaper.jpg` (please correct me if I'm mistaken), I would like to have Window store the transcoded wallpaper file on a [RAM disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive).  How can this be done?

Comment: Why? What benefit? it's hardly a mission-critical task, needing millisecond latency-free precision. Why waste RAM on such a trivial detail? I could perhaps vaguely understand if you needed precision colour mapping for a design workflow on a fully-calibrated system, but for a wallpaper... on an uncalibrated display? just...Why?

Comment: @Tetsujin Because it is waking up the hard drive from sleeping.  Also, when the hard drive is awake, it causes latency in other tasks every time the the slideshow image changes because the drive heads have to perform the seek operation.

Comment: Why is your boot drive sleeping during normal use? I know you quoted it being on `X:` but one would assume Roaming to be on `C:`, for a myriad reasons… not least of which being it's always available.

Comment: @Tetsuijin Because a properly configured computer does not write to non-volatile storage when it is idle.

Comment: Ermmm… whut? Either define "properly configured" or in some other way describe to me how a running OS will never read/write anything to cache ...

Comment: @Tetsujin I would prefer to stay on-topic and focus on answers to the question posted.  Thanks.

Comment: Then: set up a RAM disk. symlink your desired location to it. Benefit (minimally). Or see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1):

Find and configure a RAM disk software.

Then try from an elevated command prompt `mklink /D X:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes" "Y:\wherever\on\your\RAM\disk"`

If this works, you probably need to setup a scheduled task to do this on each boot.